# Custom RecyclerView adapter generating heavy lag while using in viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

My App's MainActivity class consist of ViewPager with around 10 tabs. Inside each tab I am loading ListItem using android RecyclerView. The problem occurs when user swipes right-left in ViewPager. After debugging, I found that problem occurs inside my CustomListAdapter.

I found that lags increases if I increases number of Layout Inflater inside onCreateViewHolder.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // performance hit
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    View itemViewlast = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row_last, parent, false);
    View itemViewdefault = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row_default, parent, false);

    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            break;
        case 3:
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemViewlast);
            break;
        default:
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView1);
            break;
    }

    return viewHolder;
}
```

To reduce that I shifted LayoutInflater inside the switch case itself.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            // moved here
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            break;
        case 3:
            // moved here
            View itemViewlast = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row_last, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemViewlast);
            break;
        default:
            // moved here
            View itemViewdefault = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row_default, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView1);
            break;
    }

    return viewHolder;
}
```

Now I still feel like there is some lag left. So my Question is, Is there any way to reduce this lag or shift Layout Inflater outside of the onCreateViewHolder method?

MyViewHolder Method:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, rating, genre,detailmovie,movieName,movieTime;
        public ImageView thumbNail, movieNail;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            detailmovie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailmovie);
            movieName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieName);
            movieTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTime);
            thumbNail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            movieNail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieThumbnail);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                MyViewHolder vh1 = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
                break;
            case 3:
                MyViewHolder vh3 = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder1(vh3, position);
                break;
            default:
                MyViewHolder vh4 = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder1(vh4, position);
                break;
        }
    }

private void configureViewHolder1(MyViewHolder vh1, int position) {

    final Movie movie = movieItems.get(position);

    vh1.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    vh1.rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(movie.getRating()));

    Glide.with(activity).
        load(Uri.parse(movie.getThumbnailUrl())).
        crossFade().
        placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).
        dontTransform().
        into(vh1.thumbNail);

    vh1.movieDetail.setText(String.valueOf(movie.movieDetail()));
    vh1.movieName.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getmovieName()));
    vh1.movieTime.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getmovieTime()));

    vh1.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragmentJump(movie);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post the MyViewHolder code?

Comment: @GuilhE MyViewHolder Code added.

Answer (score 0):

Try using default [caching strategy for glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation) (`DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT`), which stores the resulting image on the cache, instead of storing hte full image. 
By doing this, you reduce the amount of transformations aplied to your images (less processing -> less chances of dropping frames).

Comment: My finding was Layout Inflator is the bottleneck here. Don't you think that? Or it must be Glide?

Comment: Glide is being used when populating the view, so it is probably having some impact. Try using glide with all default options first and tell me if it made a difference. Also, it would be nice to see your actual layout file.

Comment: I removed the Glide but still lag is present. Any other suggestion? Layout file is normal with 6 views. Earlier it was working fine with ListView.

Comment: If your layout has views which require size recalculation (like `RecyclerView`) it might also cause some lag. Does your `ImageView` have some `src` attribute on the layout? It might be filling it twice, and doing so with a very large image. Just to be sure, you removed the whole image loading and the lag was still there?

Comment: yes, I removed the glide functionality but kept ImageView in Layout. I have updated my other adapter code above. If it helps.